# how to patch date onEdit in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In a form i have use angular material date picker. OnEdit i want to patch date with form date but it is showing empty , but the date is coming on the form page. In order i am fetching record from db according to id send onEdit.

I have tried to give format.In database date are stored in 18.4.2019 format.

```js
form.patchValue({Date: order.Date});
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"formControlName="dDate" id="Date" readonly (click)="picker.open()"><mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"><mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>date_range</mat-icon></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

`onEdit` date should be patch and in input field i should get date of that particular record.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
form.patchValue({Date: new Date().toLocaleString()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `order` is an `@Input()`, use `ngOnChanges` to react to values from inputs:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes.order && changes.order.currentValue) {
    this.form.patchValue({dDate: this.order.Date});
  }
}
```

In your markup the `formControlName` was "`dDate`" which different from your typescript, but they should match.